# React components get duplicated on resize/re-render even though they have unique keys

Tags: reactjs, resize

Can you please advise what is missing in my code (https://codesandbox.io/s/x2q89v613o) that causes copies of components to be created on resize even though I had assigned unique keys to them? 
Project is simple scheduler table with each cell being a component and event is also component. Some complexity added by using React Drag and Drop .. could it be that using HOC wrapper makes React do not recognize existing elements?

Thanks!!
VB

Comment: Do you mean duplication of events in cell?

Comment: yes.. please open my example and try to resize... you will see events in cells are duplicated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your `componentWillReceiveProps` with below in `WeekView`, I have added a line  `cell.events= [];`. This is clear all previous events and add the new which came in props.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.events && nextProps.events.length) {
      console.log("weekView componentWillReceiveProp got events");

      this.state.cells.forEach(cell=>{
        cell.events= [];
      });

      nextProps.events.forEach(x => {
        const start = x.start;

        const cellId = "c" + "_" + moment(start).valueOf();

        const target = Helper.getItemFromArray(this.state.cells, cellId, "id");

        if (target) {
          console.log("found");

          target.events.push(x);
        }
      });

      console.log(
        this.state.cells.filter(x => {
          if (x.events.length > 0) return x;
        })
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. It will not work because some cells will have multiple events - with your code only last event will be added . However, i like the idea .. I'll try to remove existing events before processing those from nextProps. Though it still looks hacky .. re-create same elements instead of re-sizing existing

Comment: componentWillReceiveProps will update because window size is getting re-render. so you need to clear all cells event before adding new to it. Let me modify my code

Comment: I tried this approach and removed existing events before processing those from nextProps (https://codesandbox.io/s/8znjwxjqyj). It works!

Comment: If my answer resolved your error, please make it as accepted answer

Comment: I accepted your answer. However, I still confused why React ignores the keys and hope that someone can help me to understand the reasons. 
Using workaround is a solution, but it does not make me feel confident that next time I will not get into same trouble

Answer (score 0):

The below line is causing the problem

```
tableWidth: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this._tableTarget).offsetWidth
```

**offsetWidth** is changing on screen size change and hence creating a copy.

Remove it and try.

```
tableWidth: "auto"
```

or

```
tableWidth: "100%"
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it did not change behavior (see my updated sandbox). I've added this tableWidth parameter to listen to window resize and change size of the events.. but it's not used anywhere yet because of the issue I described.

Comment: use tableWidth: "auto" or tableWidth: "100%"